# Java FileWriter how to write to next Line

Tags: java, file, newline

I used the code below to write record into a File. The record can be written in the file, but is append in one Line, each time  I call this method example:

Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World

How can I modify the code so the output look like below, so that when read the text I can use line.hasNextLine() to check?

Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World

```
        // Create file
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(c.toString());
        //Close the output stream
        out.close();

        // Code I used to read record I am using | as a seperator name and id
        String fileName = folderPath + "listCatalogue.txt";
        String line = "";
        Scanner scanner;
        String name, id;
        scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
        System.out.println(scanner.hasNextLine());
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            name = st.nextToken();
            id = st.nextToken();
            catalogues.add(new Catalogue(name, id));
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
out.write(c.toString());
out.newLine();
```

here is  a simple solution, I hope it works

EDIT:
I was using "\n" which was obviously not recommended approach, modified answer.

Comment: Please dont use '\n' the line seperators shall be different on base of platforms

Answer (score 55):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but is this what you mean?

```
out.write("this is line 1");
out.newLine();
out.write("this is line 2");
out.newLine();
...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call the method `newLine()` provided by java, to insert the new line in to a file.

For more refernce -[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

.newLine() is the best if your system property line.separator is proper .
and sometime you don't want to change the property runtime .
So alternative solution is appending \n