# out.write() in java , how to insert newline

Tags: java

When writing to a text file in java , how do I enter values into a new line

code snippet

```
while (rs.next()) {
                int sport = rs.getInt("sport");


                String name = rs.getString("name");


                out.write(sport + " : " + name);}
```

the text file populates   " value1 value2 value3...etc"
I want it to populate

```
value1
value2
value3 
.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005086/java-filewriter-how-to-write-to-next-line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If 'out' is a PrintWriter, use println().
- If 'out' is a BufferedWriter, use newLine().
- If 'out' is some other Writer, use write('\n'), or append the newLine directly to the string you're writing. If you want the system's line separator, see System.getProperty() with the value "line.separator".

Comment: Is java smart enough to turn \n into the correct line terminator for your OS (windows vs mac vs unix)?

Comment: @Patashu It is if you use println() or newLine(), not with \n.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple

`out.write(sport + " : " + name + "\n");`

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

use out.write(10); to add new line. 10 is acsii character for newline. But it is not work for Indirect/Direct Buffer type FileChannel.